# Using Google BigQuery to run multiple queries back to back

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently working a project where I'm using Google Big Query to pull data from spreadsheets. I'm VERY new to SQL, so I apologize. I'm currently using the following code

```
Select *
From my_data
Where T1 > 1000
And T2 > 2000
```

So keeping the Select and From the same, I want to be able to run multiple queries where I can just keep changing the values I'm looking for between `t1` and `t2`. Around 50 different values. I'd like for BigQuery to run through these 50 different values back to back. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm VERY new to SQL

... and I assume to BigQuery either ..., so

Below is one of the options for new users who are not familiar **yet** with [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) and/or [different clients](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) rather than [BigQuery Web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui).

BigQuery Mate adds parameters feature to BigQuery Web UI

What you need to do is

1. Save you query as below using <kbd>Save Query</kbd> Button

   [image]

Notice `<var_t1>` and `<var_t2>`
Those are the parameters identifyable by BigQuery Mate

2. Now you can set those parameters
   Click <kbd>QB Mate</kbd> and then <kbd>Parameters</kbd> to get to below form

   [image]
3. Now you can set parameters with whatever values you want to run with;
   Click on Replace Parameters <kbd>OK</kbd> Button and those values will appear in Editor. For example

   [image]

After <kbd>OK</kbd> is clicked you get

[image]

So now you can run your query

4. To Run another round with new parameters, you need to load again your saved query to the editor by clicking on <kbd>Edit Query</kbd> Button

[image]

and now repeat settings parameters and so on

You can find BigQuery Mate Chrome extension [`here`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh)

*Disclaimer: I am the author an the only developer of this tool*

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in running [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#running_parameterized_queries). The idea would be to have a single query string, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE t1 > @t1_min AND
  t2 > @t2_min;
```

You would execute this multiple times, where each time you bind different values of the `t1_min` and `t2_min` parameters. The exact logic would depend on the API through which you are using the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), and there are language-specific examples in the first link that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about sql-injection and just want to iteratively swap out parameters in queries, you might want to look into the [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) templating language (available in R as '[whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker)').

If you are using R, you can iterate/automate this type of query with the [condusco](https://github.com/ras44/condusco) R package.  Here's a complete R script that will accomplish this kind of iterative query using both whisker and condusco:

```
library(bigrquery)
library(condusco)
library(whisker)

# create a simple function that will create a query
# using {{{mustache}}} placeholders for any parameters

create_results_table <- function(params){

  destination_table <- '{{{dataset_id}}}.{{{table_prefix}}}_results_{{{year_low}}}_{{{year_high}}}'

  query <- '
    SELECT *
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
    WHERE year > {{{year_low}}}
      AND year <= {{{year_high}}}
  '


  # use whisker to swap out {{{mustache}}} placeholders with parameters
  query_exec(
    whisker.render(query,params),
    project=whisker.render('{{{project}}}', params),
    destination_table = whisker.render(destination_table,params),
    use_legacy_sql = FALSE
  )

}

# create an invocation query to provide sets of parameters to create_results_table

invocation_query <- '
  SELECT
    "<YOUR PROJECT HERE>" as project,
    "<YOUR DATASET_ID HERE>" as dataset_id,
    "<YOUR TABLE PREFIX HERE>" as table_prefix,
    num as year_low,
    num+1 as year_high
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.common_us.num_999999`
  WHERE num BETWEEN 1992 AND 1995
'

# call condusco's run_pipeline_gbq to iteratively run create_results_table over invocation_query's results

run_pipeline_gbq(
  create_results_table,
  invocation_query,
  project = '<YOUR PROJECT HERE>',
  use_legacy_sql = FALSE
)
```