# how to set named parameter on bigquery query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to use named parameters in my query on bigquery.

```
@val '123';
SELECT *
FROM [project_id:my_dataset.my_table] 
where name=@val
```

I get

`Encountered " <MAX_TOKEN_VAL> "R "" at line 1, column 2. Was expecting: <EOF>`

is there any way to set named parameters on biquery?

Comment: while, as Elliott mentioned, parameters are not supported in Web UI - you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/42542455/5221944 to see how you can use BigQuery Mate for this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Named parameters are supported in BigQuery only through the API using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), not the web UI. You can read about them in the section on [Running parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries). If you are interested in web UI support for query parameters, you can [star the feature request on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905569).